# Variable supposedly not null despite never having a value assigned

Tags: powershell

Code shortened for brevity:

```
Function Add-DatabaseUser
{
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 0)]
    [string] $samaccountname
   ,[Parameter(Position = 1)]
    [string] $username = $null
)

if ($samaccountname -notmatch "[a-z0-9]*\\[a-z0-9]")
{
    throw new [System::ArgumentException] "SAMAccountName was not in the correct format."
}

if($username -eq $null)
{
    $username = $samaccountname
}

# Code omitted...

Try
{
    Write-Host "Creating user..."
    $user = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.User") $database, $username
    $user.Login = $login.Name
    $user.Create() # Exception thrown.
}
Catch
{   
    # Code omitted.
}
```

The exception I get is as follows:

*An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, 
verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases 
defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.*

This is happening because the value of $username is null. Yet I have a if-statement at the very beginning of the script to check if it it's null, and if so, assign a value to it. But apparently the debugger evaluates `$username -eq $null` to False.

Why is this?

Edit: Should probably mention this is how I'm calling the function in PowerShell:

```
Add-DatabaseUser -samaccountname "mycomputer\username"
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem? What is `$login`? What is `$login.Name`? If you print the value of `$username` in the `Creating user` message do you get a value or `$null`/etc.?

Comment: $login is a `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login` object, which is initialised as expected. If I print the value of $username I just get an empty string. But typing `$username -eq $null` into PowerShell evaluates to false for whatever reason.

Comment: An empty string isn't `$null`. An empty string is `""` which isn't equal to `$null`. What value does `$username` have before the `if` test? What value does it have just inside the `Try` block? Does something in the omitted code modify it somehow?

Comment: According to the code, it should be null. $username is not used until the point shown in my code. I can post the full function if that's any use to you?
Also I know an empty string and null aren't the same, but PowerShell appears to show a null variable as just a blank line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is because you are typecasting the username variable as a string, and then setting it to $null as a default value.  The typecasting is causing it to become a null string, or "", which is different than $null.

Get rid of your typecast, or also evaluate :

```
if( [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($username) )
{
    $username = $samaccountname
}
```

Edit:

Original answer was the following, but there is a better way:

```
if($username -eq $null -or $username -eq "" )
{
    $username = $samaccountname
}
```

Comment: A good point about using `$null` as a default value for a string variable. This is probably the issue.

Comment: omrsafetyo is dead on. That's fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: @Jake you could also just use `if ($username) {}` which would work for both `$null` and empty string values. Or the more verbose `if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($username)) {}`.

Comment: @briantist that is also a good suggestion, and something I need to start remembering to do.  I have too many cases where I've used the logic in the answer I provided to account for these, and used your more verbose suggestion once or twice after I stumbled across it, but forgot to continue using it.

Comment: I'll make a note of that as well.